# What _would_ indicates in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The sentence is:

> However, if a machine is not managed by an Ambari agent then the client-side software would have to be manually installed.

Why *would* is used here? Can it be omitted without loss of meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Changing "has" to "would have" converts the statement "*the client-side software **has** to be manually installed*" into a form where that's only true "***if*** a machine is not managed by an Ambari agent".

If you didn't make that change, you'd have

> However, if a machine is not managed by an Ambari agent then the client-side software has to be manually installed.

This would be understood as being the same, and is probably acceptable in spoken or informal usage, but it's "more correct" to use the *would have* form.

Comment: ok, it looks like second conditional. But SC require Simple Past + would + infinitive, why it is "if a machine **is** not managed" instead of "if a machine **was** not managed"?

Comment: That's a good point (and, TBH, I'd have naturally written "must be" rather than "would have to be" or "has to be", unconsciously agreeing with the tense of the "if" clause).  Normally, one would write "*If the machine **were** not managed ...*" when talking about a machine as a counterfactual, but here we're talking about a present tense, and the "if" is used more like "whenever".